# LINQ Statement: 1 to Many

Tags: c#, linq

I need help to convert the below code to a LINQ statement:

```
    var defaultAcordConstructionType = new AcordConstructionType();

    foreach (var constructionType in ds.GetConstructionTypes())
    {
        defaultAcordConstructionType = constructionType.AcordConstructionTypes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefault.HasValue && a.IsDefault.Value);

        if (defaultAcordConstructionType != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

If it is not clear:

- I want the AcordConstructionType that is the default (IsDefault = true)
- There is a 1 to Many relationship between ConstructionTypes and AcordConstructionTypes
- Only one row in AcordConstructionTypes can be the default (IsDefault = true)

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What have you got so far? What isn't working about your current solution?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to LINQ? Won't improve performance nor readability.

Comment: The existing code works. I just want to use LINQ.  I am trying to use it more.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SelectMany` to "flatten" the one-to-many collection:

```
defaultAcordConstructionType =
    ds.GetConstructionTypes()
      .SelectMany(constructionType => constructionType.AcordConstructionTypes)
      .FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefault.HasValue && a.IsDefault.Value)
```